# How to delete users who are logged in

Tags: 20.04, openssh, tmux

We tried to remove them by killing the processes but they are still there.
This is how users appear

```
can't access   root      pts/18 tmux(1804832).%13   
can't access   root      pts/19 tmux(1804832).%15   
can't access   root      pts/20 tmux(1804832).%16                                                                                         
can't access   root      pts/21 tmux(1804832).%17   
can't access   root      pts/22 tmux(1804832).%18  
can't access   root      pts/23 tmux(1804832).%19  
can't access   root      pts/24 tmux(1804832).%20  
can't access   root      pts/25 tmux(1804832).%22  
can't access   root      pts/27 tmux(1804832).%23  
can't access   root      pts/28 tmux(1804832).%24  
can't access   root      pts/29 tmux(1804832).%25
```

Comment: Please elaborate. What gives the above output? Do you really mean "delete" the users? Which processes are you referring to? Why the tag [tag:linux-headers]?

Comment: That's the `root` user. You can't delete it.

Comment: I want these users to be logged out

Comment: I no longer want to see this message "USERS CRITICAL - 11 users currently logged in "

Answer (score 3):

You have a `tmux` session running, where the root user is logged in.

To view your `tmux` sessions, run:

```
tmux ls
```

This will give you a list with one or more open sessions, like this:

```
$ tmux ls
session-name: 6 windows (created Tue Mar 12 08:47:53 2024)
```

To destroy the session(s), run this:

```
tmux kill-session -t session-name
```

This will kill the session and remove all associated users that are logged in to the session.

Another option is to attach to your `tmux` session and log out all users manually - but judging from your question, it seems you want to shut down the session entirely.